# ActiveX component can't create object (comReport)

Tags: dll, asp-classic, activex

I am trying to print a pdf report and it is not printing and giving this error. 
Error Type:
ComReport (0x800A01AD)
ActiveX component can't create object

I have registered the ComReport.dll with my OS.

This works fine on our developemtn and production server but is not working locally on my machine.  And I need for it to work on my local so I can debug some stuff and see what query is being ran.  Page I am trying to debug is classic asp in .net 2003.  I googled some stuff and they are just saying to make sure browser has ActiveX enabled...which it does!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a missing reference.
You can use "Depends.exe" (Shipped with Visual Studio) to determine missing libraries.